AutocompleteTextView Not showing suggestions, when rendered inside BottomSheetDialogFragment
I have implemented an AutocomplteTextView inside a BottomSheetDialogFragment.
Below is my xml for bottomsheet layout
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_top_round_tabs"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/siq_8"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/dp_40">

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/orgListFilterEdt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/siq_10"
            android:background="@drawable/cir_rect_black"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_arrow_bottom"
            android:hint="@string/organisation"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/siq_8"
            android:paddingVertical="@dimen/siq_4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/siq_text_14"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <requestFocus />
        </AutoCompleteTextView>

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/userListFilterEdt"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/siq_10"
            android:background="@drawable/cir_rect_black"
            android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_arrow_bottom"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:hint="@string/user"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:paddingHorizontal="@dimen/siq_8"
            android:paddingVertical="@dimen/siq_4"
            android:textSize="@dimen/siq_text_14"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/orgListFilterEdt" />

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_update_filter"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/userListFilterEdt"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/siq_4"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:text="Update filter"
            android:textColor="@color/color_lynktrac_logo"
            android:textSize="@dimen/siq_14"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/userListFilterEdt"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/userListFilterEdt" />

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cv_apply_changes"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/siq_10"
            app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/colorBtnDone"
            app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/siq_14"
            app:cardElevation="@dimen/siq_8"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tv_update_filter">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_apply_changes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/siq_20"
                android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/siq_4"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingVertical="@dimen/siq_4"
                android:text="Apply Changes"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/siq_text_12"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>

Below is my DialogFragment class
interface OrgUserFilterCallback { fun onOrgSelected(org: String) fun onUserSelected(user: String) fun onApplyChanges() fun onUpdateFilter() }

class BottomOrgUserFilter( initialOrgList: List<OrganisationsResponse.Data>, initialUserList: List<OrgUsersResponse.Data>, private val filterCallback: OrgUserFilterCallback? = null, private val context: Context ) : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
private lateinit var binding: LayoutBottomsheetGeofenceLandingBinding
private var orgList: List<String> = initialOrgList.map { it.name }
private var userList: List<String> = initialUserList.map { it.name }

companion object {
    const val TAG = "BottomOrgUserFilter"
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    dialog?.window?.setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE)
}

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View {
    binding = LayoutBottomsheetGeofenceLandingBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
    return binding.root
}

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    val bottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(view.parent as View)
    bottomSheetBehavior.state = BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED
    bottomSheetBehavior.peekHeight = resources.displayMetrics.heightPixels

    setupDropdowns()
    setupListeners()
}

private fun setupListeners() {
    binding.orgListFilterEdt.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
        filterCallback?.onOrgSelected(orgList[position])
    }

    binding.userListFilterEdt.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ ->
        filterCallback?.onUserSelected(userList[position])
    }

    binding.cvApplyChanges.setOnClickListener {
        filterCallback?.onApplyChanges()
        dismiss()
    }

    binding.tvUpdateFilter.setOnClickListener {
        filterCallback?.onUpdateFilter()
    }
}

private fun setupDropdowns() {
    val orgAdapter = ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, orgList)
    binding.orgListFilterEdt.apply {
        threshold = 0
        setAdapter(orgAdapter)
    }

    val userAdapter = ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, userList)
    binding.userListFilterEdt.apply {
        threshold = 0
        setAdapter(userAdapter)
    }
}

fun setOrgList(newOrgList: List<String>) {
    if (isAdded) {
        orgList = newOrgList
        val orgAdapter = ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, orgList)
        binding.orgListFilterEdt.setAdapter(orgAdapter)
        orgAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged()
        notifyAll()
    }
}

fun setUserList(newUserList: List<String>) {
    if (isAdded) {
        userList = newUserList
        val userAdapter = ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, userList)
        binding.userListFilterEdt.setAdapter(userAdapter)
        userAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged()
        binding.userListFilterEdt.isEnabled = true
        
    }
}

I am unable to rectify the cause of problem.
I have tried making every changes provided in the internet, though not getting successful outcome.
I have worked around making changes in the layout and parent layout but still no workaround.
Thanks
